# Can't load image

Tags: php

As you can see, there is no image. What's wrong with this?

```
$displayProdCat .= '<div class="product">
<a href="productdetail.php?prodid='.$ItemId.'"><img src="Customer/images/product'.$ItemNo.'.jpg" width="170" height="150" /></a>
<h3>'.$ItemName.'</h3>
<p class="product_price">Php '.$Price.'</p>
<a href="shoppingcart.php?prodid='.$itemId.'" class="add_to_cart">Add to Cart</a></div>';
```

[image]

Comment: Try one of the link paths directly in the browser to see if they work.

Comment: Try `src="/Customer/images/product'.$ItemNo.'.jpg"`.  Using an absolute path vs a relative one might fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a wrong image url is specified. Look at the source.